# HTML Form Data into Ruby Formula

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, forms

I'm trying to create a page where I can type into a textbox, on that page, and then create a variable using the data.

So far, I have:

```
<FORM NAME = frmName>

First Nme: <INPUT TYPE = Text NAME = txtFirst value ="">

Last Nme: <INPUT TYPE = Text NAME = txtLast value ="">

<P>
Total: <INPUT TYPE = Text NAME = txtFullName value = "">
<P>
<Input Type = Button NAME = b1 VALUE = "Submit" onClick = calculate()>

</FORM>
```

The JavaScript is working that allows me to run the onClick command, but what I really need has to have a page where I can insert data, and then populate a variable with that data.

For example.  Type my first name and last name into the textboxes on the page.  Then a variable running in the background, with be created.  (ex. variable = first + name). This variable can then be used in the code on the rest of the page.  Please also keep in mind, I don't want to add the form data into a database.

Is it possible to do this in ruby only?

Comment: I don't see which part of this question uses Ruby on Rails. Anyways, I didn't understand what you're exactly asking? You want to write a Ruby code that adds first name and last name and store result in an another variable? or you want to write a Ruby code that adds first name and last name values from text boxes and store in a Ruby variable? If you want the second option then I am sorry to say but it's not possible. Maybe you could elaborate a little about what you're really after so we can help?

Comment: It's the second that I want. I want to create html forms, input data, submit, and be able to use the data in a variable in the same view. Thanks for your clarification

Comment: It's not possible because Ruby code will be compiled before generating the HTML. I am sorry but you need to reply on JavaScript for this. :)

Comment: If you want to use Ruby on Rails, use Ruby on Rails. I don't know what you're asking for here other than "How can I do this in Rails?" That's something best answered by a comprehensive guide on the subject.

Comment: When you write in a language, even HTML, it's important to pay attention to the proper syntax. You're not correctly quoting your parameter values for your tags, which is a bad practice. While a browser will attempt to parse your HTML, you're more likely to end up with errors. Don't deliberately code to take advantage of fixups provided by the browser.